# What is an elegant way to serve whole duck livers?

Tags: duck, liver

Duck livers fried in butter are my favorite "chef's snack".  I sometimes opt for roast duck for dinner so I can have my 4:00 treat.  I've recently found a source of same day slaughter duck livers in 1-2 pound quantities.  This sounds like a great opportunity for a delicious appetizer.  I'm thinking of a Chinese spoon presentation, but it needs something to make it special.  Are there any classic presentations/pairings or other novel ideas?

Comment: Personally I love pairing duck liver with cherries. Take a look at this recipe, perhaps you can find some inspiration there: http://www.latimesmagazine.com/2011/10/balsamic.html Oh, and I think this question will probably be closed (recipe request).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Are you asking for things to go with duck liver? Are you asking how to present a piece of liver nicely? What is the current problem you have?

Answer (score 0):

For presentation:  Philo dough cups precooked with either sprigs of dill or whittle blueberries on a Sterling Silver Plate or Platter.  Sterling Silver makes anything look elegant.